Spring cloud gateway rewritePath and display route
I use spring boot and spring cloud gateway mvc
Server 1
locahost:8082
it's context path is /crm
Server 2
localhsot:8001
it's context path is /acme/crm
When a call is do server 1 like
locahost:8082/crm/bff/book/1
i would like to call
localhsot:8001/acme/crm/book/1
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> inventoryServiceRoute() {
    return route("crm_bff")
            .route(RequestPredicates.path("/bff/**"), http("http://localhost:8001/acme/crm"))
            .before(rewritePath("/(?<segment>.*)", "/${segment}"))
            .build();
}

I get a 404
Also is there a way to display the url gateway is trying to call
Edit solution
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> inventoryServiceRoute() {
    return route("crm_bff")
            .route(RequestPredicates.path("/bff/**"), http("http://localhost:8001/acme/crm"))
            .before(rewritePath("/crm/bff/(?<segment>.*)", "/acme/crm/${segment}"))
            .build();
}


Remove /acme/crm from the http part and put it as a prefix to the first argument of rewrite

not working it try to call: http://localhost:8001/crm/bff/book/1
